Is the only way to get a RequestVerificationToken to place a form somewhere on the page in ASP Net Core?
I kept getting a 400 bad request error when trying to post to my razor page. When I compared the request headers between the page where I could not post to another one in my application where posting worked I noticed this difference:
Header from failed post:
Authorization: Negotiate oXcwdaADCgEBoloEWE5UTE1TU1AAAwAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAABXCiOIKAGFKAAAAD7Fyyg2YfDoN+FYR4J5+KlSjEgQQAQAAAPqrk2LNTZm4AAAAAA==
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"

Header from successful post:
RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8GbSvkkuhNhDgf5mY4viJRAeZYsuMasP2upKhs0e1XfUtN0S7xovkXBP2dVmxILxj8zsUK_MGpy4_INi1UzQifImKuFGufxCkM-SjXuWqZ55BzVTKWhqoeDVrGFcs-3BM73h0BLfASFfazLURCH45P1KskBn2ayn5Azg6_vxtsKOP3aqhb6MFqaFo-ycHJDQ6w
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0

I then realized that the page that could post successfully had a form on the page, the one that couldn't did not. The page with no form did not have a hidden field containing the RequestVerificationToken.
I added an empty form to the page and then it was able to post successfully and in the page source I could see that a RequestVerificationToken was now present.
My question is, must a form always be present, even if empty if one is going to post from a page to the server? The reason I had no form here is because there was nothing for the user to fill out, just a grid with delete buttons where clicking delete posted to the server with the grid row id to delete the corresponding entity from the database.
If the only way for this to work is to put an empty form on the page that's fine, just wanted to make sure there wasn't a more elegant solution I'm not aware of.

I'd be careful with posting negotiate tokens... (I removed it just in case...)

Since they're both hitting the same endpoint, then yes you'll need an anti-forgery token for both pages.  You can instead send anti-forgery as a token in the header, but this is a bit of work both to implement and to test.  (definitely not as elegant...)


My question is, must a form always be present, even if empty if one is
going to post from a page to the server?

Well, based on your scenario and descriptions it can be said that, No, you do not need to have a form present on the page to post to the server in ASP.NET Core.
There are more elegant solutions to include the anti-forgery token in your requests, especially when dealing with scenarios like yours where user input forms are not required.
As said at the begining, you can include the anti-forgery token in a meta tag and read it in your JavaScript code. This method avoids the need for an empty form.
For intance, you could write like below:
<meta name="RequestVerificationToken" content="@Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken" />

Once you get this then, you could pass the 'RequestVerificationToken' within your request header as well.
Alternatively, you could generate Token from Server-Side. If your architecture involves API requests, you can configure your endpoints to handle and expect anti-forgery tokens.
However, the implementation completely depends on the requirement and the scenario. If you can tolerate having an empty form on the page, it's the most straightforward and secure way to leverage ASP.NET Core's anti-forgery protection. It integrates seamlessly with existing form helpers and provides a strong defense against CSRF attacks.
On the other hand, If you have a strong reason to avoid an empty form and have the development expertise, consider the alternatives mentioned above with caution, carefully evaluating the security implications.
Note: Please refer to this official document for more details.
